# How to turn off antialiasing in Graphics class?

Tags: java, graphics

I have been using the following code with a `Graphics2D` buffered image

```
g.setRenderingHint(
  RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, 
  RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
```

to ensure the image looks correct when scaled in.

If I use the `Graphics` class instead of `Graphics2D` it appears to auto anti-alias and present a zoomed image as blurred.

Is there a way to turn off anti-aliasing with the `Graphics` class so I do not have to use the `Graphics2D` class?

Comment: Basically every `Graphics` is also a `Graphics2D`. You can usually just cast the `Graphics` to `Graphics2D`, and set the rendering hints as desired.